# Geocoding API not responding fast enough timeout issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Geocoding API not responding fast enough (use Geocoder.configure(:timeout => ...) to set limit).

I have search by address that time API through I got a Latitude and Longitude but now generate unpermitted parameters for Latitude and Longitude.

Comment: show your current params.

Comment: yes but time limitation error generate.

Unpermitted parameters: lat, lng

Geocoding API not responding fast enough (use Geocoder.configure(:timeout => ...) to set limit).

Comment: What about setting a bigger `timeout`(as the message says) to see if u get a proper response, or try to measure how much time the request is really taking to see if there`s no problem if your code.

Comment: Show your config

Answer (score 2):

This is late but it may help someone, create a file in config/initializers called geocoder.rb and add this line

> Geocoder::Configuration.timeout = 15